# htaccess redirect with www and non www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched all over and I can find ways to direct www to non and the other route as well. But it feels like I have a bit of a different case.

I am trying to use a vanity URL to direct users to an alternate url and path. So that when a user enters www.vanityurl.com or vanityurl.com it directs them to domain.com/path/id

This is what I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/path/id/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This works great for www. But, test.com either fails or redirects to just domain.com with out the path.

Help!?

Comment: Do you want to redirect `test.com/anything_after` to `domain.com/path/id/anything_after` or are you looking for specifics numbers or an id to come on the test URL? Does your host have cPanel or any control panel?

Comment: If you are just requesting `http://test.com` – that URL does not _have_ a path segment. Nothing to match, ergo `$1` will be empty.